# How to get unique ID of document from firestore in angular and store all ID in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

How to get unique ID of document from firestore in angular and store all ID in an array and later compare it with user defined ID and if it matches than do not set the data field and if entered ID did not match than set the data field with the value provided by user. How to achieve the above?

Comment: what does it mean by id of document here, is it some kind of reponse like from firestore which can be like [{someId: value}.{otherId:value}] . and from where do i get the use defined id, do you have some input for user to provide values?. Please mention your requirement clearly and if possible give some code snippet.

Comment: i mean, how to store document name in an array and later compare element of that array(in which document stored) with a string entered by user, so that any data field  can be set on particular document.

Comment: Thank you  a lot for your reply. My issue has been resolved.

Comment: If you solved your issue please consider adding an answer, this will help other users that might find a similar issue, otherwise please consider closing your question